# iPhone projects needs "Pull-up to refresh" feature

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Many iPhone projects use "Pull-to-Refresh" pattern to load more results (usually new data from the server.

In my project I want to do just the opposite: "pull-up to refresh". I want to load old data from the server but I need that the user request the data pulling up the UITableView.

How can I do it? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what I've been using:

First of all you have a view holding the "Pull up to refresh message", and assign it to:

```
[pullUpView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, [tableView rectForFooterInSection:0].origin.y, [tableView bounds].size.width,pullUpView.frame.height)];
```

Then you setup two delegate methods as below to track the dragging.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {    
    if (scrollView.isDragging) {
        CGFloat thresholdToRelease = [pullUpView frame].origin.y - [scrollView bounds].size.height;
        CGFloat thresholdToLoad = thresholdToRelease + [pullUpView frame].size.height;

        if (([scrollView contentOffset].y >= thresholdToRelease) && ([scrollView contentOffset].y < thresholdToLoad)) {
            [pullUpView reset];
        } else if ([scrollView contentOffset].y >= thresholdToLoad) {
            [pullUpView indicateThresholdRearched];
        }
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    CGFloat thresholdToAction = [pullUpView frame].origin.y + [pullUpView frame].size.height - [scrollView bounds].size.height;

    if ([scrollView contentOffset].y >= thresholdToAction) {
        if (!performingAction) {

            [pullUpView startLoading];

            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
            [tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, [pullUpView frame].size.height, 0)];
            [UIView commitAnimations];

            /* do your things here */
            performingAction = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

At the end revert the tableView's contentInset to hide the pullUpView.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much ! Just some questions about your code: Can you explain me what does the methods [pullUpView reset]. [pullUpView indicateThresholdRearched], [pullUpView startLoading]?

Comment: And one last question: Should I add it to my tableView using [self.tableView addView:pullUpView] ? (tableView is my UITableView IBOutlet add to a UIViewController)

Comment: Those are the methods' names copied from https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh. To reflect the state of the "pulling" action.

Comment: Yeah. I use [tableView addSubview:pullUpView].

Comment: How do you declare the pullUpView?

Comment: @James: I preallocate the view with a large negative Y so it's hidden by default. When the drag reach the threshold I then set it to the table footer's coordination.

Comment: @nevin I mean how do you declare that variable?  Though now I'm wondering about the margin, but I can probably figure that one out on my own after playing with it.

Comment: @nevin Actually, you can ignore that question.  I used another code snippet I found and kind of just combined the two to get it mostly working how I want.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

"Pull up to refresh" sounds a bit odd, especially if the table is more than one screen long. But if you really want to do it, check out the [Three20](http://three20.info/) open source library. There you'll find the "pull down to refresh" functionality, and you can just adapt it to suit your needs.