# UITableview add table cells based on scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to do an app that has a similar functionality like the tweeter app.

I have a table view with 10 cells, and I want that when I scroll down and get to the 5th cell, the table view adds another 10 cells to the current view and so on.

The content for these cells is set by running a method which returns an array of 10 elements, from which I use to populate the new cells.

I don't know how to add more cells to the current table view and how to check when I reach the 5th cell or the end of all the current cells so that a new set of 10 cells is automatically added.

I am thinking that I will use [tableView reloadData] to repopulate the tableview, and I will call this after I know that I've reached the end of all the current cells, but I don't know how to check when I've reached that end.

Any thoughts on that? Is it possible to check when I've reached the end of all the cells of a table view?

Comment: possible duplicate http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/18876-paging-pagination-load-more-uitableview.html

Comment: I'm not interested in having this functionality based on a button, just by using the scroll. I've started displaying the indexpath.row number and I see that based on scrolling, it returns exactly what I want, which is the number of the table cell. But how do I add more table cells to the current table, without overwriting the current cells?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `UITableView` is just a subclass of an `UIScrollView`, so you can implement the `UIScrollViewDelegate` functions and do whatever you want in them.

You can implement the

`-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

delegate function and check whether you reached the end of the table

`if (scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height == scrollView.contentView.frame.size.height)
{
...
}`

should do the trick, or if you want to start adding new rows a bit earlier then just subtract some points.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not exactly what you were looking for, but it is quite similar...

Here is your start point: https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh

And here are some more interesting links for you:

1. [iPhone projects needs "Pull-up to refresh" feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684441/iphone-projects-needs-pull-up-to-refresh-feature)
2. [UITableView rows load asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551035/uitableview-rows-load-asynchronously)

Answer (score 1):

There are many open source projects doing it. To find them, you can go to, for example, to http://www.cocoacontrols.com/ and search for "refresh" or "pull to refresh", or "tableview".

Many of these projects are provided with examples on how to use them with a tableview

Answer (score 1):

Use the scroll view delegate to get direction of scroll  (will get called if you use table view)

```
#pragma mark:scrollView delegate
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    offset=scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    offsetx=scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    DLog(@"%f",offset);
}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
{

    DLog(@"%f************%f",offset,sender.contentOffset.y);
    if(offset>sender.contentOffset.y)
    {
        directionUp=NO;
    }
    else {
        directionUp=YES;
    }

}
```

then use this tabe view delegate method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



        if(directionUp&&(indexPath.row>dataSource.count-3))
        {
            [self performSelector:@selector(appendTableView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];// appendTableView fetches next ten data element
        }


}
```